# asp.net scrollable gridview with fixed header and footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I see a lot of discussion for this issue, but they are old, and not cross browser.

I have a gridview in my asp.net project with many rows, I need that header is fixed when user scroll the grid, gridview allow sorting, so user can click on header.

Maybe using paging solve my problem, but I must use scroll .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add `scrollable div`

```
<div style="overflow:auto; widht:100%; height:YourHeight" >
<asp:GridView>
   .....
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that this not solve my problem, using div I have all gridview scrollable, I want to scroll only on rows having header and footer static